# JQ selecting multiple conditions where one is substring

Tags: json, select, match, jq

I have done quite a bit of searching and most responses I find are close, but not quite what I am looking for.  Parsing a JSON file with this:

```
cat file.json | jq -r ".[] | select(.name == \"${VALUE}\" or .guid == \"${VALUE}\") | .name"
```

works as expected, it selects the item where either the .name or .guid equals ${VALUE} and prints out the name.

However, I would like the .guid match to be a substring or regex match.  Trying this does not work:

```
cat file.json | jq -r  ".[] | select(.name == \"${VALUE}\" or .guid | contains(\"${VALUE}\")) | .name"
```

I think I am fairly close, just missing something being new to jq...

Comment: Include a [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a pair of parens.  Also, it's usually much better to pass in variables using `--arg` or `--argjson` or some such.  So, in light of UUOC and other considerations, I'd go with something like this:

```
< file.json jq -r --arg VALUE "$VALUE" '
   .[]
   | select( (.name == $VALUE) or (.guid | contains($VALUE)) )
   | .name'
```

Or, depending on your requirements, you might prefer to use this `select` clause:

```
select( (.name == $VALUE) or (.guid // "" | contains($VALUE)) )
```

Comment: Thanks!  So looks like I had the correct commands just improperly formatted.  Thanks for the tip on passing variables, that will definitely come in handy!  Thanks again!  Nice tip about dumping the cat command too...